# How can I collect selected checkboxes from all child checkbox components in vue?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table where the row elements are all populated by child components. There is a checkbox in each of these child components. Now I want to get all checked checkboxes at once. I could use prefs emit as two way binding and update an array or object on the parent but I am wondering if there is better way for this.

Here a short example for the template part:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Check </th>
            <th> Title </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <list-tbody v-for="element in elements" :element="element"> </list-tbody>
</table>
```

and this is the child component

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td> {{element.title}} </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Typically in Vue, there is no *need* to get the checkboxes themselves, just the state of the data that is bound to them. Why do you need the checkboxes specifically?

Comment: Yep you are right @Bert . I have a sub table on each table (component) as well. This way each component can hold the (collapsed or not) data by itself. Other way I either needed an extra value (isCollapsed) or I had to store the data elsewhere. That is why I decided to use components instead.

Comment: I wouldn't do it like in the answer below. Keep the data in the parent and emit an event to update the parent on each selection change or use Vuex to update your elements array (recommended). Then you can create a filter method to get only the selected elements. Something like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/ckx496n6/). If this is what you're looking for I can add an answer and add more details.

Comment: Actually @AWolf I don't want to use vuex just for such a case.

Comment: Using events is also OK. Just have a look in the fiddle at the second component. I just haven't added the filtering there.

Comment: Yes @AWolf I think your second example is the best solution for this situation. I could use that as the answer if you add it here as well.

Comment: The event approach(vs the Vuex approach) in a similar scenario has some support in the official documentation:
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you could handle this in two ways:

- Use Vuex and mutate the elements array from the child component.
- Emit an event on each selection click event to the parent and the parent will update the elements array.

You prefer the second because you're not using Vuex and that's OK.

Once you're having the data "linked" between child component and parent you can use a filter method to only show the selected elements.

Please have a look at the demo below or the fiddle from my comment.

```js
const listTbodyVuex = {
props: ['element'],
 template: `
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" @click="selected">
        </td>
        <td> {{element.title}} </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
  `,
  methods: {
   ...Vuex.mapMutations(['changeSelection']),
   selected(evt) {
     //console.log('clicked', evt.target.checked, this.changeSelection)
      // changeSelection mutation could be also called with-out mapping
      // this.$store.commit('changeSelection', ...);
      this.changeSelection({
       id: this.element.id, selected: evt.target.checked
      });
    }
  }
}

const listTbodyEvents = {
 props: ['element'],
 template: `
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" @click="selected">
        </td>
        <td> {{element.title}} </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
  `,
  methods: {
   selected(evt) {
     console.log('clicked', evt.target.checked)
      this.$emit('selected', {
       element: this.element,
        newSelection: evt.target.checked
      })
    }
  }
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
 state: {
   elements: [
      {
       id: 0,
       title: 'first',
        selected: false
      },
      { 
       id: 1,
       title: 'second',
        selected: false
      },
      {
       id: 2,
       title: 'third',
        selected: false
      }
      ]
  },
  mutations: {
   changeSelection(state, {id, selected}) {
     let element = state.elements
       .filter((element) => element.id === id)[0];
      element.selected = selected;
      //console.log('update element', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element)));
      Vue.set(state.elements, element.id, element);
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  store,
  data() {
   return {
     elements: [
      {
       id: 0,
       title: 'first',
        selected: false
      },
      { 
       id: 1,
       title: 'second',
        selected: false
      },
      {
       id: 2,
       title: 'third',
        selected: false
      }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
   ...Vuex.mapState({
     vuexElements: (state) => state.elements
    })
  },
  components: {
   listTbodyEvents,
    listTbodyVuex
  },
  methods: {
   updateElement(data) {
     let element = this.elements
       .filter((element) => element.id === data.element.id)[0];
      element.selected = data.newSelection;
      // console.log('update', element)
    },
    filterSelected(data) {
     // console.log('filter',  data.filter((item) => console.log(item.selected)))
     return data.filter((item) => item.selected);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.0/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<h1>Example with vuex</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Check </th>
            <th> Title </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <list-tbody-vuex v-for="element in elements" :element="element" :key="element.id"> </list-tbody-vuex>
</table>
  <pre>only selected: {{filterSelected(vuexElements)}}</pre>
  <pre>{{vuexElements}}</pre>
  
<hr/>
<h1>Example with events</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Check </th>
            <th> Title </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <list-tbody-events v-for="element in elements" :element="element" :key="element.id" @selected="updateElement"> </list-tbody-events>
</table>
  <pre>only selected: {{filterSelected(elements)}}</pre>
  <pre>{{elements}}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really stick to emitting values to maintain separation of your components. That being said, you can do the following if you really wanted to grab the data all at once:

First, you'll need a data attribute in your child component that your checkbox uses with `v-model`. For the sake of this example, let's just call it `checkbox_value`. Once you've done that, you can do something like the following in your parent component method:

```
var checkbox_values = [];
this.$children.forEach(function(child) {
    //you can check the child type here if you have other non-checkbox children
    checkbox_values.push(child.$data.checkbox_value);
});
```

Of course, I wouldn't encourage you to do something like this, but you'll have to make that judgement call.

Note: The above will return values only. You could push object key/value pairs instead!